# python itertools permutations for powers of 2 is too slow

Tags: python, performance, permutation, python-itertools

I'm having a very strange issue and can't seem to find a way to fix it.

The following code finds the prime factorisation of `n`, puts the prime factors into a list then finds all possible sum variations of the prime factors and prints out the unique values of that list.

Example: The prime factors for 44 are 2*2*11 so for 44 it would print out

```
2,2+2,11,2+11,2+2+11 = 2,4,11,13,15:
```

Here is my code:

```
import math
import sys
import itertools
from itertools import permutations

def primes(n):
    primfac = []
    d = 2
    while d*d <= n:
        while (n % d) == 0:
            primfac.append(d)
            n //= d
        d += 1
    if n > 1:
       primfac.append(n)
    return primfac


def primecombo(n):
    b = []
    for i in range(1, len(primes(n))+1):
        for subset in permutations(primes(n), i):
            b.append(sum((subset)))
    a = list(set(b))
    a.sort()
    return a
```

the code itself seems to work fine and efficiently for the most part but for some very strange reason it becomes ridiculously slow when you're dealing with any number who's only prime factor is 2.

if you try print primecombo(444444) or print primecombo(23452823) it'll print the results almost instantly but if you try 2048 or 4096 it becomes really really slow.

Can anyone see why this is the case and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: 23452823 has only 7 factors while 2048 has 11. Since getting permutations is exponential, it just is unbearably longer. Also, you are recalculating the primes on every iteration, store them in a variable instead.

Comment: Also, you do not require permutations  of your primes, only combinations. That should significantly improve your time.

Comment: Thanks Olivier that's sped things up significantly

Comment: This can be sped up even more when a factor is there multiple time by using a counter of factor and iterating on its combinations, I'll write a full answer later if nobody did

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short answer

Using `itertools.permutations` makes your algorithm sum redundant partitions of prime factors. Using `itertools.combinations` should be a considerable improvement, but we can still do better.

### Long answer

Finding all permutations with `itertools.permutations` makes your function `primecombo` run in factorial time with regard to the number of factors, worst than exponential.

Let's have a look at the time-complexity with regard to the number of factors *k*. The dominant step is iterating over `permutations(primes(n), len(primes(n))`. There are *k!* permutations and you are suming each of those. The time-complexity of your algorithm is thus

> O(k * k!)

That is why 2048, that has 11 factors, is unbearably longer than 23452823, that has 7 factors, to process.

#### Alternative

Fortunately, visiting every permutation is unnecessary. By example, if you have the factors 2, 3, and 4, you will be summing every permutation of 2, 3 and 4 which is redundant. One quick improvement would be to sum combinations instead, but even then we would sometimes sum the same partition twice when there are factors that appear more than once.

The following solution solves this issue by keeping track of prime factors with a `Counter` instead of a `list`. This later allows us to use `itertools.product`.

This algorithm is able to find the sums you need for 4096 in a matter of milliseconds, see time-complexity analysis below.

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter

def primes(n):
    primfac = Counter()
    d = 2

    while d ** 2 <= n:
        while (n % d) == 0:
            primfac[d] += 1
            n //= d
        d += 1

    if n > 1:
       primfac[n] += 1

    return primfac

def primecombo(n):
    factor_sums = [[p * e for e in range(exp + 1)] for p, exp in primes(n).items()]

    sums = set(sum(partition) for partition in itertools.product(*factor_sums))

    return sums

primecombo(4096) # {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24}
```

#### Time complexity

The time-complexity depends on the distribution of your prime factors. The worst scenario comes if there are *k* distinct factors. Our `itertools.product` then has size 2<sup>k</sup>. Thus making the algorithm

> O(k * 2<sup>k</sup>)

Comment: Could you please add into your great answer the running time of OP's original code and your code?